# Where and group conflict?

Tags: mysql, group-by, where-clause

I have a table like this:

```
mysql> select * from studentscore;
+------------+-----------+-------+
| student_id | cource_id | score |
+------------+-----------+-------+
|          1 |         1 |    80 |
|          1 |         2 |    90 |
|          1 |         3 |    85 |
|          1 |         4 |    78 |
|          2 |         2 |    53 |
|          2 |         3 |    77 |
|          2 |         5 |    80 |
|          3 |         1 |    71 |
|          3 |         2 |    70 |
|          3 |         4 |    80 |
|          3 |         5 |    65 |
|          3 |         6 |    75 |
|          4 |         2 |    90 |
|          4 |         3 |    80 |
|          4 |         4 |    70 |
|          4 |         6 |    95 |
|          5 |         1 |    60 |
|          5 |         2 |    70 |
|          5 |         5 |    80 |
|          5 |         6 |    69 |
|          6 |         1 |    76 |
|          6 |         2 |    88 |
|          6 |         3 |    87 |
|          7 |         4 |    80 |
|          8 |         2 |    71 |
|          8 |         3 |    58 |
|          8 |         5 |    68 |
|          9 |         2 |    88 |
|         10 |         1 |    77 |
|         10 |         2 |    76 |
|         10 |         3 |    80 |
|         10 |         4 |    85 |
|         10 |         5 |    83 |
|         11 |         3 |    80 |
|         12 |         4 |    99 |
|         13 |         5 |    74 |
+------------+-----------+-------+
```

I want to show student_id and students' average scores that are higher than 80.

The output I want is like this:

```
+------------+-------------------+
| student_id | Average           |
+------------+-------------------+
|          1 |             83.25 |
|          4 |             83.75 |
|          6 | 83.66666666666667 | // and how can I make this result shorter like 83.67?
|          7 |                80 |
|          9 |                88 |
|         10 |              80.2 |
|         11 |                80 |
|         12 |                99 |
+------------+-------------------+
```

I've tried the following codes

```
mysql> select   student_id, avg(score) as average_score
    -> from     studentscore
    -> group by student_id
    -> where    avg(score) >= 80;
```

and it gave me an syntax error.

I know by rules the where clause should go before the group by clause but I can't because the where clause depends on the result from the group by clause, and if I switch their position it will give me another error("Invalid use of group function").

Can some one tell me how to get the table I want?

Comment: What database are you using here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using MySQL.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen sorry I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 3):

use "having" instead of "where"

Comment: Thanks! I just started learning sql so I didn't know there is a 'having'...

Answer (score 1):

use `having` instead of `where`.
Here's the difference:

1. with where you can write a predicate that will be applied to each row
2. with having you can write a predicate that will applied to each group

and in your case, the 2nd is the only solution that can work.

Answer (score 0):

```
select   student_id, avg(score) as average_score
     from     studentscore
     group by student_id
     having avg(score) >= 80;
```

Comment: I did sir. I have less than 15 reputation so it doesn't display publicly...

Answer (score 0):

`where` applies a filter to your data before grouping has taken place, whereas `having` applies a filter post-grouping. `round(,2)` will format as you also ask:

```
select student_id, round(avg(score), 2) as average_score
from studentscore
group by student_id
having average_score >= 80;
```

Comment: In SQL Server you can't use a select alias in the `HAVING` clause.  This _would_ work in MySQL though.